# Error while copying .war file to the remote server using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, devops, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy `.war` file (from `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abc/target/abc.war` to `/home/tomcat/webapps/`) using ansible playbook which is installed in the same server where jenkins run. Getting the following error,

> Could not find or access '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abc/target/abc.war' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option

Verified the remote server connection via ssh authentication using

```
ansible all -m ping, output is 192.168.*.***
| SUCCESS
```

**Deployment file**,

```yaml
---
 - name: Deploy war  
   hosts: Appservers  
   tasks:
     - name: Stop Tomcat  
       command: /home/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/bin/shutdown.sh

     - name: Delete old war  
       command: rm -rf /home/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/webapps/abc*

     - name: Copy the war file  
       copy:  
         src: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abc/target/abc.war  
         dest: /home/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/webapps/  

     - name: Start Tomcat  
       command: /home/apache-tomcat-9.0.37/bin/startup.sh
```

I don't understand why I am getting the above error when everything is fine. Images are uploaded for reference.

PS: war file owned by jenkins, host and remote users=root, deployment.yaml owned by root and has 777 rights.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Posting code, error messages and commands is specifically listed as a bad practice. It is usually not readable at all, people trying to help you cannot copy/paste the content if needed for a fast check, and it impairs the hability of the search engine to index the content. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63523327/edit) and copy the textual content of your images into code blocks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apology for my mistake, edited and replaced image with text

Comment: It's better to format text in quoting or code block. See my edit for your future questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and sure will follow the guidelines in future.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the result of `ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BsmartFramework/target/BsmartFramework.war` on the ansible controller (i.e. the machine running the playbook) as an evidence it is there ? Note: if the file is present on the target and not on the controller, you have to use `remote_src: true` as suggested by your error message.

Comment: Edited my question with ls -ll, Playbook is running on ansible controller itself and file is present in the controlller not on the target.

Comment: Which user is running the playbook on the controller? Are you sure all folders along the path are at least `r-x` for that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as Zeitounator suggested its permission issue. My workspace had read only permission because of that i was getting the error, now i changed the permission to r-x and its working fine. Thank you Zeitounator!!